# Isolating a prefactor in an analytical expression

Tags: pattern-matching

I have a large mathematica expression that looks roughly like

```
f = A1 Exp[a1 x] + A2 Exp[a2 x] + b1/x + b2/x^2 + c0 + c1 x + c2 x^2
```

where all the $A_n,a_n,b_n,c_n$ are symbolic constants.

how can I isolate the prefactor of x ? i.e some function that checks the pattern of $f$ and returns $c_1$ ?

Comment: Hi Amir. Welcome to this site! You mentioned "I have a large mathematica expression ...", thus please post the *Mathematica* expression/code, not the LaTeX formula, so others can directly copy & paste it into *Mathematica* and test it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CoefficientArrays` or `CoefficientList` for this.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Mathematica' pattern like `Times[p_, x]` that works well in case your symbolic constant does contain `x`. `Cases` will extract all matches. Please, see the following example:

```
f := A1 E^(a1*x) + A1 E^(a1*x) + b1/x + b2/x^2 + c0 + (c1 + 9023/x - 23.2)*x + c2*x^2;
Cases[f, Times[p_, x] :> p]
```

The output is:

```
{-23.2 + c1 + 9023/x}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is the command `Coefficient`. For example

```
Coefficient[a Exp[d x] + b x + c x^2 + 1/x + 2/x, x]
```

gathers all the terms in `x`, returning `b`.Similarly,

```
    Coefficient[a Exp[d x] + b x + c x^2 + 1/x + 2/x, a]
```

gives Exp[d x].

Comment: Great ! this is what I was looking for :)